# mongoose access current value before updating it inside findOneAndUpdate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following code

```js
let doc = await IssueModel.findOne({ content_id })
    IssueModel.findOneAndUpdate({
        content_id
    }, {
        $set: {
            assigned_user,
            status: doc.status==='done' ? 'done' : 'ongoing'
        }
    })
```

I'm looking for a shorter way to omit the first line, and access **status** current value before updating it inside the **findOneAndUpdate** , something similar to **this** maybe.
I want to update **status** only if it's different from 'done'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to save as well

```
let doc = await IssueModel.findOne({ content_id })
if(doc.status !== 'done') {
 doc.status = 'ongoing'
 await doc.save();
 return res.json({success: true})
}
res.json({success: true});
```

Comment: yup, this is a better solution than mine, thanks. (though i'm still looking for an answer on whether it is possible or not to access the old value inside findOneAndUpdate)